# Is there a way to count and loop with plain SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following tables:

**album:**

*albumID*, albumTitle, albumReleaseDate, albumLabel, albumDigitalImg, albumCoverStory

**albumTrack:**

*trackID*, **albumID**, **recordingID**, albumTrackNumber, cd

---

*italic* = primary key

**bold** = foreign key

---

The question is as follows:

> List the total number of tracks on each album that has any. Give the
>   column containing the total number of tracks a sensible name and use
>   albumId to identify each total.

My only idea would be to iterate over each albumID and check how many tracks are assigned to it but obviously loops aren't a thing in plain SQL? Is there any way to do this using plain SQL?

This only checks how many tracks are assigned for albumID 1, not for all albums and I'm really lost as to how I could do this without a loop.

```
SELECT COUNT(albumID)
FROM albumTrack
WHERE albumID = 1;
```

I'm using Oracle.

Comment: Kindly share some sample data and desired output.

Comment: sample data and desired output: https://i.imgur.com/DFsxJBk.png

Comment: The question is trivial. And answer for its is each sql tutorial. (count employees in department) Type of rdbms is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query will give you the number of tracks against each albumID,if any.

```
SELECT albumID,count(trackID) as NumberOfTracks
FROM albumTrack
Group By albumID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Select ab.albumID, 
    Count(Distinct trackID) As trackCount
From album ab 
Inner Join albumTrack at 
    on at.albumID = ab.albumID
Group By ab.albumID;
```

This will give the count of tracks for each album.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for the counts per albumID.
For just that, a select on albumTrack alone with a `GROUP BY` on the albumID should be sufficient.

```
SELECT albumID, COUNT(*) AS TotalTracks
FROM albumTrack
GROUP BY albumID
ORDER BY albumID
```

But if albumTrack.albumID can be NULL, or isn't a foreign key on album.albumID?
Then an `INNER JOIN` on the "album" table should still be used.
To make sure that it only counts for albumID's that actually exist in the "album" table.

```
SELECT
 tracks.albumID, 
 COUNT(*) AS TotalTracks
FROM albumTrack AS tracks
JOIN album ON album.albumID = tracks.albumID
GROUP BY tracks.albumID
ORDER BY tracks.albumID
```

And if you'd like to show the counts per albumTitle:

```
SELECT
 a.albumTitle, 
 COUNT(t.trackID) AS TotalTracks
FROM album a
JOIN albumTrack t ON t.albumID = a.albumID
-- WHERE a.albumID = 1
GROUP BY a.albumID, a.albumTitle
ORDER BY a.albumTitle
```